# RPGLE Data Strucutre Array Lookup

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have created a data structures array and i want to look based on key combination. i.e. in the below DS i want to lookup and get index if tblName and tblElement and tblDivision are matching and then return tblRes value.

```
    D TblAryDs        DS                  qualified dim(9999)                    
    D  tblName                       3                                           
    D  tblElement                   10                                           
    D  tblDivision                   5                                           
    D  tblRes                        2                                           

//Not Sure How to do the below lookup
      idx = %lookup(tblName:TblAryDs(*).tblName) && %lookup(tblElement:TblAryDs(*).tblElement) && %lookup(tblDivision:TblAryDs(*).tblDivision);                                
      if idx > *zeros;                                                                                   
         return TblAryDs(*).tblRes;
      endif;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 D TblAryDs        DS                  qualified dim(9999)                    
 D  key
 D    tblName                     3a   overlay(key)                                        
 D    tblElement                 10a   overlay(key:*next)                                        
 D    tblDivision                 5a   overlay(key:*next)                                        
 D  tblRes                        2a           

  /FREE
    idx = %lookup(tblName + tblElement + tblDivision 
                  :TblAryDs(*).key); 
    if idx > *ZEROS;
      return TblAryDs(idx).tblRes;
    endif; 
  /END-FREE
```

Note: as coded above, `%LOOKUP()` will search all 9999 elements.  If you have to search repeatedly for different values, add the `ASCEND` keyword to the array and use `SORTA` to sort it prior to searching.  Lastly, keep track of how many elements are actually used in the array.

```
idx = %lookup(tblName + tblElement + tblDivision 
                  : TblAryDs(*).key : nbrElemUsed);
```

This way `%LOOKUP()%` will perform a much faster binary search of only the active elements.

Comment: If my array has the following elements, BIL-123-123-11 and BIL-456-456-22 and i need to lookup for the send row this code won't be working. Since  the lookup returns the first row always.

Comment: @Sekar Sorry misunderstood what you needed.  How about now?

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks. One question though since i will be adding elements at run time, sorting the array after adding every element would be time consuming right. The actual scenario is that instead of looking into a file every time i want to cache the results as much as possible to reduce IO. I would very much like to know your opinion on this. Would sort and lookup be time consuming or the file IO?

Comment: File I/O is more costly, but not as much as you might think due to the nature of the single level store.  You won't actually be hitting the disk for every I/O.  The `SETOBJACC` would even allow you to preload the entire file into memory.  There's still a bit of overhead going through the DB...but if [premature optimization really is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)  I'd start simple and just do the file I/O.  Then move to telling the system to cache it, before building my own caching

Comment: Otherwise, if I built my own caching, I'd look at loading the whole thing then sorting it.  Problem is, do you need to worry about the data changing in the file thus making your cache or it stale?